# Can I pass an onpressed into a CupertinoDialog from a separate dart file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter application with a CupertinoDialog. I created the Dialog in a separate dart file so I can call it in multiple places. This is my Dialog:

```
 void scanQR(BuildContext context) {
  showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: Text("Scan Qr Code"),
          content: Text("Scan the QR Code"),
          actions: [
            CupertinoDialogAction(
                isDefaultAction: true,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Cancel",
                  style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.systemRed),
                )),
            CupertinoDialogAction(
                isDefaultAction: true,
                onPressed: () {
                  
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Scan",
                  style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.systemBlue),
                ))
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

And this is how I call it on the second screen:

```
   onPressed: () {
      scanQR(context);
    }),
```

On my second screen, I have this function that I would like to be called if the Scan action on the dialog is is clicked.

```
  Future scanQrCode() async {
    try {
      String scanResult = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ffff00', 'cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      setState(() {
        scannedCode = scanResult;
      });
      print(scannedCode);
      if (scannedCode == widget.selectedUserId) {
 
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

When I pass the function as parameter, the scanQrCode runs automatically before the button is pressed.

How can I go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the name of the separate Class your Dialog button was created in

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Function in parameter of your widget or function.

```
 class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onPressed;
      
  const MyButton({
        Key key,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => onPressed(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then

```
return MyButton(onPressed: () {
   print('clicked');
});
```